# How to add a condition to difflib?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, difflib

I want to get the closest match for my row from another data frame but with a condition, I currently have it like this:

```
df['a'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x,df2['a'].astype(str)))
```

but i want it to get the closest match from `df2['a']` when `df['b'] == df2['b']`. How can i put this in the syntax?

Comment: i believe you want [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html).

Comment: @Terry Doesn't seam to work on strings